# At FORM's onsubmit event, all <INPUT> values return empty strings

Tags: forms, validation, getelementbyid

I have a validation function tied to a form's `onsubmit` event. When it runs, my `<input>` objects return empty strings in the `value` attribute even though I have typed in some text.

For example, the mark up is:

```
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
```

the following:

```
 document.getElementById("email").value
```

returns an empty string "" even if there is some value entered in the form.

I hope the screen shot below captures the situation:

[image]

I must be missing something very basic. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one `<FORM`> in the page (but only one is visible at any one time), and there are more than one instances of `<input id="email">`. The wrong element with id `email` was being selected.

Hope this answer might be of use to somebody else too.